# How to write like I'm in display-math mode?

Tags: formatting, symbols

when I compile:`\subsection{subsection 1} $$\int x^2 dx$$`
i get this large nice shaped integral sign but i do not want this integral to appear neither individually nor at the middle of the page.
if ı use `\subsection{subsection 1} \int x^2 dx` ı get a small, non pretty looking integral sign which ruins the appearance of the page.
how can ı solve this issue?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get?  Please clarify what constitutes "an ugly shaped integral".

Comment: a small integral sign the one you would get in:  \subsection{this is a subsection}     $\int x^2 dx$

Comment: It is impossible to guess what your question is. what does "ugly" mean? All we know so far is that you have used some markup that you have not shown and you do not like the character. You could use a different font but you have not said what font you are using. Please include a small complete document that shows the issue, and say how you want it to change.  (possibly not related but `$$` is not supported latex syntax)

Comment: sorry guys, ı am going to edit the question and make it more clear

Comment: A full size `\int` would never fit in the running text (as in `$\int$`) without messing up line spacing. Thus text mode math uses the small version of the symbol this is normal. If the expression becomes complicated typeset it displayed instead.

Comment: @EnesSenel It is helpful if you provide `MWE` of your code or an image which should show your requirement, please look into https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks about `MWE`...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:  I think that for the O.P., display style  integrals look more lascivious than those messy textstyle…  I somehow agree with this point of view.

Comment: @Bernard the real question then is why put an integral inline?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Probably to keep it for oneself – rather selfishly…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My hunch is that you want is `$\displaystyle\int$`, to produce a full-size integral symbol while in inline math mode. However, as [@Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) has noted in a comment, you may also be interested in `\medint\int` of the [nccmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath) package. The symbols produced by `\medint\int` and `\displaystyle\int` are shown in the following screenshot, along with the default inline-math integral symbol.

[image]

Do be aware, though, that the large size of the displaymath-style integral symbol will surely wreck the appearance of the paragraph in which the symbol occurs -- unless something like `doublespacing` is in effect, in which case the appearance of the paragraph is beyond repair from the outset and the occurrence of `$\displaystyle\int$` will inflict only minimal further typographic damage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
$\int h(x)\,dx \quad \medint\int h(x)\,dx \quad \displaystyle\int h(x)\,dx$
\end{document}
```

Comment: A compromise would be adding the `\medint` command from nccmath

Comment: @Bernard - Many thanks for this suggestion! I've updated my answer to incorporate `\medint\int` as a possible solution to the OP's typesetting objective.